# C++ Vector become empty in instance class after pushing some data

Tags: c++, oop, vector

```
class Bank {
  private:
   string bankName;
   vector<Account> accounts;

  public:
   Bank(string name){
    bankName = name;
   }
   Account registerAccount(string name){
    Account account(name, rand());
    accounts.push_back(account);

    return account;
   }
  void checkMyAccount(Account account){
    cout << accounts.size();
    cout << bankName;
    for(Account acc : accounts){
      if(acc.getBankId() == account.getBankId()){
        cout << acc.getName();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I am new in c++, and do you know why in another method my vector become empty after pushing some data? this is full code https://repl.it/@mufti1/CircularFrontSigns

Comment: What other method? Where is your test code?

Comment: how are you using the class????

Comment: The definition of `Account` and the `main` function are missing. Please add them as well to the question

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have posted. The error is in the code you haven't posted. Probably the issue is that your code is referring to two different `Bank` objects when you think there is only one `Bank` object.

Comment: I've Account class but forgot to add here, and here in main 
int main() {
  string name;
  cout << "input your name: ";
  cin >> name;
  Customer cust(name);
  Bank bank("BCA");
  Account customerAccount = cust.requestAccount(bank);
  bank.checkMyAccount(customerAccount);
}

Comment: @Mufti So where in your code are you adding accounts to the BCA bank? There's nothing in the code you've posted that does that.

Comment: @john i update the post, add the full code in repl

Comment: This is usually a sign that you have more objects than you expect, and that you're modifying a copy of what you think you're modifying.

Comment: @Mufti Please, don't use the comments section for clarifying the question. Instead, edit the question itself. Also, external links to the code are not suitable here, the question itself should contain the full code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that you have two different bank objects

```
Bank bank("BCA");
Account customerAccount = cust.requestAccount(bank);

Account requestAccount(Bank bank){
  return bank.registerAccount(name);
}
```

The bank object in requestAccount is a **copy** of the bank object in `main`. So you add an account to the copy but not to the original in main.

To solve use a reference

```
Account requestAccount(Bank& bank){
  return bank.registerAccount(name);
}
```

By using a reference `Bank&` the bank object is not copied, and your code alters the Bank object in main instead of the local copy.

For some reason beginners often assume that C++ passes objects by reference by default. But this is not the case, if you want a reference you have to ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
Account requestAccount(Bank bank)  //<--- you are passing by value
{
    return bank.registerAccount(name);
}
```

When you call `requestAccount(bank)`, you create a copy of the original `Bank` object:

```
  Account customerAccount = cust.requestAccount(bank);
```

To fix this, change the function to:

```
Account requestAccount(Bank& bank) {   //pass by reference
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in code you did not show in the post : your `requestAccount` method takes a `Bank` object by copy instead of by reference. You should delete the `Bank` copy constructor (or make it private)  to prevent these things from happening again.